# Help to show that the Nehari set is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, banach-spaces, smooth-manifolds

Let $I\in C^2(\mathbb{R^n})$. And define $K=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R^n}-\left\{0\right\}: I^\prime(x)x=0 \right\}$ and suppose that for each $u\in S^{n-1}$ the line $\phi_{u}(t)=tu$, $t\geq0$ intersects the set $K$ in a unique point. Show that $S^{n-1}$ is homeomorphic to $K$.

Here is my attempt:

Define the application $H:S^{n-1}\to K$ by $H(x)=t_{x}x$ where $t_{x}$ is the unique  time when $\phi_{x}(t
_x)\in K$, and my difficult is to show that $H$ is continuous. Of course that the inverse of $H$ is given by $H^{-1}(v)=\dfrac{v}{||v||}$ which is continuous. So if I can prove that $H$ is continuous then the problem is solved. And I tried to show that $H$ is continuous in the following way:

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence on $S^{n-1}$ such that $x_{n}\to a \in S^{n-1}$ so for $H$ be continuous we must have $t_{x_{n}}x_{n}\to t_{a}a$  but my difficult is to show that $t_{n}\to t_{a}$. Any hint?